# tab key not working on PrimeFaces datatable filters when horizontal scroll bar exist

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I m using primefaces 5.0 with JSF 2.1.28. My datatable having multiple columns with horizontal and vertical scroll bar, it having filter text box to filter data. Problem is, **When i'm pressing the tab key on filter text field its not moving to next filter text field**

Whereas when there is no horizontal scroll bar in tadatable then tab key on filter text field moving accordingly.

Comment: Tried PF 5.3 or 6.0-SNAPSHOT?

Comment: @Kukeltje Jan, No im using primefaces5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution, use `scrollWidth` attribute in `<p:datatable>` tag.

```
<p:datatable scrollHeight="150" scrollWidth="500"> 
   <p:column>you columns</p:column>
</p:datatable>
```

while using scrollWidth, whenever you press tab OR shift+tab focus goes to next OR previous component of the page.

**this was tested with Primefaces 5.0**